# output name instead of id

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to see how long it takes to resolve a bug based on the area that it affects. My result set looks like this

```
 areaid       Average Resolution/Closure Time (days)
    1            425.57929613
    2            510.00435347
    3            342.90670739
```

I want to replace the area values with the name of the area rather than the id number. The name of the area is in another table (area table). the table i'm performing the code on is called bug table. So this is what I want.

```
 area_name     Average Resolution/Closure Time (days)
  ABC            425.57929613
  DEF            510.00435347
  GHI            342.90670739
```

The area table looks like this

```
 areaid          area_name   
    1            ABC
    2            DEF
    3            GHI
```

i think i need to use a join (all bugs is tied to one area, but area categories may not be tied to a bug) so that my code is able to call the area name based on the primary key area id. My question is basically how do i use a join (or any other function) to replace the area key id with the name of the area. I've read about joins but I dont understand how you choose which table to call from.  As well, i have other code and i'm worried about how this new addition would affect the existing code.

```
SELECT area, AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF (second, Opened, GREATEST(COALESCE(Resolved , Closed), COALESCE(Closed, Resolved)))) /86400 AS "Average Resolution/Closure Time (days)"
FROM bug
WHERE Resolved IS NOT NULL AND Closed IS NOT NULL 
AND Title <> "test"
GROUP BY area
```

Comment: does your second table has area id? on what basis one would say area 1 belongs to say "ABC" or "DEF" or others?

Comment: @SMA the second table does have an area id, i amended the question to include a sample of the area table.

Comment: Based on the WHERE clause, the COALESCE's seem rather pointless?

Comment: Hint: Use `JOIN`

Comment: @LukStorms i think i made a mistake in my code. I wanted to include bugs that have either resolved and/or closed dates but not bugs that dont have either but i think the way i wrote it will only take bugs that have both.

Comment: @helloworld You should use `OR` instead of `AND` in that case. Put that part of the `WHERE` clause in parentheses because of the precedence issues when you combine `OR` with `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

You will join the bug table to the [ReferenceTable] on the id of the areaName, then select the alias rt.areaName from the join:

```
    SELECT 
    ar.area_name as Area,
 AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF (second, Opened, GREATEST(COALESCE(Resolved , Closed), COALESCE(Closed, Resolved)))) /86400 AS "Average Resolution/Closure Time (days)"
    FROM bug as bg
    JOIN Area as ar
    on bg.areaid = ar.areaid
    WHERE Resolved IS NOT NULL AND Closed IS NOT NULL 
    AND Title <> "test"
    GROUP BY ar.areaName
```

Comment: MySQL uses backticks, not square brackets, around names. Square brackets are for SQL-Server.